# How to create a list by iterating two different type of list, using java lambda expressions?

Tags: java, lambda

How can i change following code using java 8 lambda expressions. Below is my code:

```
public class Main {
class Student {
            String name;
            int mark;
            String parentName; 

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
            public int getMark() {
                return mark;
            }
            public String getParentName() {
                return parentName;
            }
        }

        class Empl {
            String name;
            long salary;
            String managerName;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
            public long getSalary() {
                return salary;
            }
            public String getManagerName() {
                return managerName;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Student> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Empl> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
            // Storing data to list1 and list2
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Student s :list1) {
                result.add(s.getName());
                result.add(s.getParentName());
            }
            for(Empl m :list2) {
                result.add(m.getName());
                result.add(m.getManagerName());
            }
            System.out.println(result);     
        }
    }
```

In the above code i have used for loops for adding elements from two different lists. How can i use lamba expressions to perform the same steps above?

Comment: That code does nothing. list1 and list2 are empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does the same:

```
List<String> result = Stream.concat(
        list1.stream().flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.getName(), s.getParentName())),
        list2.stream().flatMap(m -> Stream.of(m.getName(), m.getManagerName()))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you need to make sure that an `ArrayList` is created just use `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` instead.

Comment: Thanks Benko, if i want to store parentName to another list. How we can do this on same code ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, but is this what you're looking for?

```
list1.forEach(s -> {
    result.add(s.getName());
    result.add(s.getParentName());
});
list2.forEach(m -> {
    result.add(m.getName());
    result.add(m.getManagerName());
});
```